# SaltStack - How to use a dictionary in pillar and loop through those values in template file?

Tags: python, salt-stack, configuration-management

I'm trying to make our configuration a little more modular. Currently, we have mostly hardcoded template files per environment that are matched to each environment with jinja in the init states. I'm splitting up the states, configs, and adding some default values that need to be maintained in the same config value across all enviornments.

Here's an example of my pillar:

```
/../pillars/amq/amq.sls
default_routes:
  Queue1:
    - from_uri: 'activemq:fromSomeURI1'
    - process_ref: 'processorName1'
    - to_uri: 'activemq:toSomeOutURI1'
  Queue2:
    - from_uri: 'activemq:fromSomeURI2'
    - process_ref: 'processorName2'
    - to_uri: 'activemq:toSomeOutURI2'
```

Here's an example of my template file:

```
/../salt/amq/conf/camel.xml.template
lines lines lines
lines lines lines
...
      {% for route, args in pillar.get('default_routes', {}).items() %}

        <route>
          <from uri="{{ route.from_uri }}"/>
          <process ref="{{ route.process_ref }}"/>
          <to uri="{{ route.to_uri }}"/>
        </route>

      {% endfor %}

...
lines lines lines
lines lines lines
```

What I need to be able to do is add a dictionary of values to the pillar, and loop through that list of default values, building out the default routes across all environments, from within camel.xml.template. The pillar then will also store environment specific values that I'll add to the file in a very similar manner.

Any help is much appreciated. I've tried a ton of different things and either get an error or the default lines are removed from the file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few inconsistencies with how you define your pillar.

Using [this tool](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/), to translate your YAML to Python gives

```
    "default_routes": {
        "Queue1": [
          {
            "from_uri": "activemq:fromSomeURI1"
          }, 
          {
            "process_ref": "processorName1"
          }, 
          {
            "to_uri": "activemq:toSomeOutURI1"
          }
        ], 
        "Queue2": [
          {
            "from_uri": "activemq:fromSomeURI2"
          }, 
          {
            "process_ref": "processorName2"
          }, 
          {
            "to_uri": "activemq:toSomeOutURI2"
          }
        ]
      }
```

when I presume you meant something like

```
"default_routes": {
    "Queue1": {
      "to_uri": "activemq:toSomeOutURI1", 
      "process_ref": "processorName1", 
      "from_uri": "activemq:fromSomeURI1"
    }, 
    "Queue2": {
      "to_uri": "activemq:toSomeOutURI2", 
      "process_ref": "processorName2", 
      "from_uri": "activemq:fromSomeURI2"
    }
  }
```

You should change your YAML to

```
default_routes:
  Queue1:
    from_uri: 'activemq:fromSomeURI1'
    process_ref: 'processorName1'
    to_uri: 'activemq:toSomeOutURI1'
  Queue2:
    from_uri: 'activemq:fromSomeURI2'
    process_ref: 'processorName2'
    to_uri: 'activemq:toSomeOutURI2'
```

But even then, there is a flaw in your template

```
{% for route, args in pillar.get('default_routes', {}).items() %}
```

This line will set `route` to key name and `args` to the dictionary. So for first time, `route` will be `Queue1` and `args` will be the rest of dictionary.

You must change things `{{ route.from_uri }}` to `{{ args.from_uri }}` because args is the actual dictionary which has keys like `from_uri`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've made those updates, but I'm still not getting any output for the lines in the for loop. The file that is generated from the template doesn't generate anything for what the for loop should be outputting. There are no errors either.

Comment: @user797963 First of all you should see if `default_routes` is set properly for the minion. A `salt "your_minion" pillar.items` should reveal if default_routes pillar is properly set. If it is, then we can move to next step in debugging.

Comment: Huge help, thank you so much. This set the ground work for me to get a handle on salt pillars and made it clear to me how it's just YAML translated to python that you then can access via Jinja (that pillar.items command to see the pillar values the minion can access was huge). That YAML to python tool is invaluable too. Thanks again!